# PHP: Find largest value from results of two MySQL database queries

Tags: php

**I have the following two `mysql_queries`:**

**1.**

```
$primary_img_query = "SELECT imgWidth, imgHeight FROM primary_images WHERE imgId=$imgId";
$primary_img_data = mysql_query($primary_img_query) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());
```

**2.**

```
$secondary_img_query = "SELECT imgWidth, imgHeight FROM secondary_images WHERE primaryId=$imgId";
$secondary_img_data = mysql_query($secondary_img_query) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());
```

What I need to do is find the largest value of both `imgWidth` and `imgHeight` from each query, and then find the largest value between the two found values. I need both said largest values to end up in variables.

All values in `imgWidth` and `imgHeight` are positive integers greater than zero.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

---

I was thinking I could put the results from both `imgWidth` and `imgHeight` in each query in separate arrays, then combine the arrays, and use `max()` to find the largest(highest) value. Would that work?

Comment: These two queries are coming from the same database right?

Comment: Also are you looking for the largest image or an individual largest imgWidth and largest imgHeight even though they don't belong to the same primaryId?

Comment: @momo - Sorry for the slow response. Both queries *are* coming from the same database, but from *different* tables. And I'm looking for the largest `imgWidth` and the largest `imgHeight` *regardless* of if they belong to the same image. The `primaryId` is used to relate multiple entries in the `secondary_images` table, to a single image in the `primary_images` table. I'm using the information to set up the dimensions of the container to house images, so I want the maximum width needed, and maximum height needed. Need to know anything else? Sorry I didn't specify those things.

Comment: @momo - I was thinking perhaps I could put the results of `imgWidth` and `imgHeight` from both queries in an array, combine both arrays, and then use `max()` to find the largest value from each. Would that work?

Comment: I think that would, but it is faster to do it from the SQL layer. I post an answer that will get you the individual largest width and height irrespective of the image. I hope that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should give you MAX for the width and height given the two need not to be associated with anything. You could also filter the set. For example, by primaryId below, assuming the primaryId is a number, you want to filter for primaryId less than 2

```
SELECT MAX(imgWidth) maxWidth, MAX(imgHeight) maxHeight FROM (
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, primaryId FROM primary_images
    UNION 
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, primaryId FROM secondary_images
  ) as MaxHeight
WHERE primaryId < 2
```

You would then store the results as variables then use it to size your container.

Comment: thank you. I'll have to test it when I get home tonight. But I'm curious; I left fields out of the original queries I posted. I'm also querying imgURL and imgTitle in both queries. Would it be faster to have the original set, plus the ones you posted in the above answer, or to have the originals *with* imgWidth and imgHeight, and use the method I suggested? I want whatever is most efficient.

Comment: It depends on the size of your database. If it is large dataset then querying via SQL is faster since you don't have to iterate through in your code. If it is large, you will incur network cost bringing the data from the database to your code + calculating the max value. Also, are you saying that you want to associate largest height/width with its imgUrl and title? What if there is more than one imgUrl/title with the same max height/width? Not too clear on that question yet.

Comment: Again, sorry for taking so long to respond. I won't be home for another two hours. So, the database should't ever be more than 500 records in either table, so max would be 1000 records in all. To answer your question, I *won't* be wanting to associate height/width with any imgURL and/or title. Those are in the query to be used to create the img tags for the images themselves. However, I noticed that there are no `WHERE` clause in your queries. I'm looking for the max width/height for a specific set of images in the table, associated with the `primaryId`. Does this mean it won't work?

Comment: You could. Also since these two fields are independent and not associated with anything, you could issue a single query with both MAX there. I will update my answer to reflect this comment

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that out. So, then you think having two separate queries, with the size of database in question, is fine?

Comment: Yes, 1000 records are small by database standard.

Comment: So I'm finally testing the code. Any chance you could explain the steps that are going on here, or point me to a link that could? I have a couple questions. I'm guessing the variables the max values will be associated with are `maxWidth` and `maxHeight`? Also, the `WHERE` clause will always be equal to a specific value, however I'm curious if I can place the `WHERE` clause inside each of the `SELECT`s as from `primary_images`, the `WHERE` clause will be defining `imgId`, not `primaryId`? I'm also not sure what the `MaxHeight` at the end of the query is referring to.

Comment: I figured it all out! Thanks so much for all the help. It works like a charm. I'm going to need some more help in the next little bit. If you're willing and able, let me know.

Comment: Glad to help :) just post the new question and I will help if I can

Comment: I have a further question to your answer. The code is working great, but I remember you specifically asking me if I just needed the largest height and width values, or if needed to know which was the largest image. I'm finding I need to know if the largest height value, and the largest width value, belong to the same image. Can I amend the query to find this? I was thinking perhaps there is a way to find the `imgId` of both values, and then compare them. Is that possible with the code in it's current construct?

Comment: @stefmikhail Let's post that to a new question (if you haven't already). I remembered that being not as easy in a single query, but let me check again and answer that in that other question

Comment: Thanks for offering. Here's the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425936/amend-sql-max-query-to-find-corresponding-fields-value

Comment: @stemikhail I've answered your question. It should work with 2 queries for that question