# Amend SQL MAX Query to Find Corresponding Field's Value

Tags: mysql, sql

**I have the following query:**

```
$imgDimensions_query = "SELECT MAX(imgWidth) maxWidth, MAX(imgHeight) maxHeight FROM (
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth FROM primary_images WHERE imgId=$imgId
    UNION 
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth FROM secondary_images WHERE primaryId=$imgId) as MaxHeight";
```

It's working fantastic, but I would like to know how I can find the value of the column `imgId`, as well as the table name, for both the `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` values?

The reason I want this is I need to know if the `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` values belong to the same item in the database.

I'm wondering if this is possible by amending the current SQL query?

---

What would be perfect is if, along with querying the `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` values, a boolean could be set up to output `true` if both the `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` belong to the same entry (at least once).

I'm thinking, since the image data in `primary_images` is unique from the data in `secondary_images` (and vice versa), a boolean could be set up in each of the queries, and as long as one `true` exists, `true` is output. Does that make sense? Is that possible?

---

I have managed to put together a second query which uses the values of `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` from the first query to output the number of images in a specific set that hold both values. All I really care about is if there *is* or if there *isn't* one or more images that meet the above requirement, so again, a boolean would be better than the total number. If you have an idea of how to amend the following to show a boolean instead of the number of results, let me know!

I have been reassured that with a maximum number of entries in both tables being under 1000, using two queries instead of one shouldn't cause a hit to speed. If you think so as well, and if combining these queries into one is ridiculous, then let me know that as well.

**The second query:**

```
$haveDimensions_query = "SELECT sum(rows) AS total_rows FROM (
    SELECT count(*) AS rows FROM primary_images WHERE imgId = $imgId and imgWidth = $maxImageWidth and imgHeight = $maxImageHeight
    UNION ALL
    SELECT count(*) AS rows FROM secondary_images WHERE primaryId = $imgId and imgWidth = $maxImageWidth and imgHeight = $maxImageHeight
) as union_table";
```

Comment: What if there are several images that share the maximum width and several that share the maximum height, and some of them have both (possibly more than one image), how would you like to report that? Please add a data sample and the desired output, preferably covering the case I mentioned, too.

Comment: @Andriy M - Excellent question and point. I'm looking to see if the maximum width and the maximum height belong to the same image. In other words, as you said "...and some of them have both (possibly more than one image)...". Even if a boolean was set up to show this, that would be good. I don't care if more than one image has the max height, or the max width. I only care if at least one has both the max height, and the max width. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: @Andriy M - What would you like concerning a data sample. I'm new to all of this and I'm not sure of the lingo. Does my previous comment clarify my desired output?

Comment: I think yes, it does, thanks. That is, I understand it like this: your ultimate goal is to return an image (or images) with both the maximum width and the maximum height, and you actually don't care about images that have only one maximum attribute but not the other. Is it correct?

Comment: Upon reading your update, I stand corrected: it seems like you don't want the images, you only want to know about the fact that at least one image has both maximums.

Comment: @Andriy M - Yes that's right! That and the maximum values. So to state it (hopefully clearer... it's late): I don't want the images. I only want to know if at least one image has both maximums, as well as both maximum values (which is it returning at this time). Clear?

Comment: Yes, this time absolutely clear, thanks.

Comment: @Andriy M - Does that mean you can help?

Comment: There is one option which I think should do the job. It seems far from optimal, so I'm thinking of alternatives. I'll post it anyway, as someone may find a better solution faster by mere looking at my poor one.

Comment: @Andriy M - Well anything you can offer is appreciated. What's your idea? Why don't you post it as an answer (if you want), and we can talk about it?

Comment: You could simply add `> 0` after `sum(rows)`, that would give you a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in two queries, it's probably easier to read that way.
First query is what you have to get to get the max height and width.

You then can issue the second query which looks like:

```
SElECT primaryId FROM (
   SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, imgId AS primaryId FROM primary_images
    UNION 
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, primaryId FROM secondary_images
) as union_table
WHERE imgWidth = [maxWidth] and imgHeight = [maxHeight];
```

Where `[maxWidth]` and `[maxHeight]` are the two values that you get from previous query. If they belong to the same image ID, you will have query result greater than zero, if not this query will have no result.

If you need to know which id is belong to which table, you could create artificial column (e.g. source) and your query would become:

```
SElECT primaryId, source FROM (
   SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, imgId AS primaryId, 1 as source FROM primary_images
    UNION 
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, primaryId, 2 as source FROM secondary_images
) as union_table
WHERE imgWidth = [maxWidth] and imgHeight = [maxHeight];
```

Note that there is now artificial column called source. So if your result from query is

```
primaryId     source
4             1 
4             2
5             2
```

You know that `imgId` 4 from `primary_images` as well as 
`primaryId` 4,5 from `secondary_images` match with the max height and max width of the previous query

And finally, if you just want to know whether there is image that is matching or not, per our comments and discussion below, you could do:

```
SElECT count(*) AS imgCount FROM (
   SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, imgId AS primaryId FROM primary_images
    UNION ALL
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, primaryId FROM secondary_images
) as union_table
WHERE primaryId = $imgId and imgWidth = [maxWidth] and imgHeight = [maxHeight];
```

Where `imgCount` will be zero if there is no matching image or greater than zero otherwise

Comment: Thanks mono. I'm testing it out. Curious however, do I need to use PHP to extract the values from the first query, place them in variables, and then use the variables in place of `[maxWidth]` and `[maxHeight]`?

Comment: @stefmikhail That's correct. You need to do exactly what you just wrote. Making this as one query is possible but it will make it harder to read. Given your number of records is not large, it might better and easier to read if you do two queries.

Comment: So I placed the variables inside, and I think that's the right thing to do. However, I'm getting the error: `Unknown column`. I believe this is because we are fetching `primaryId`. The `primary_images` table does not contain a `primaryId` column; It contains a `imgId` column. I have a feeling it's more complex than just swapping `primaryId` for `imgId` in the primary_images part of the query, because you're selecting `primaryId` right at the beginning of the query.

Comment: @stefmikhail You could alias imgId as primaryId and the query would work. Put SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, imgId as primaryId FROM primary_images on the first clause of the UNION

Comment: Something about this was bothering me, and I think I have just pinpointed what it is. Because both the `primary_images` table, and the `secondary_images` table use columns entitled `imgId` to uniquely identify their entries, there is the chance that there might be an entry in question in both tables, that have the same value for `imgId`, which, unless I'm mistaken, makes the query you have provided, problematic.

Comment: Could we instead set it up so that both selects from `primary_images` and `secondary_images` have the `WHERE` constraint, and if at least one record is found from either, then true? Also, I'm sure I'm using the wrong terms to talk about these things. Is `imgId` a column, or a field? And when I'm talking about a `SELECT` statement, is that what I should call it, or is there another term for it?

Comment: If what you want just to detect whether there is a img with the same max width and height, all you need is to detect whether the record count is non zero or not. If you need to know which image that width and height belong to, you have the imgId and if that image is non-unique between primary and secondary image table, you could create artificial column (e.g. source) in the select query so you know where is the image is from. I could put a more detailed answer if you need to in the answer

Comment: I think what I want is your first statement. I want to detect if an entry in either the primary_images table, or the secondary_images table have the max values for both their height and width values. Should that be simpler than what we have been doing?

Comment: If that's what you want without knowing a specific ID, then yes, it could be simpler. Change the first query "SElECT primaryId FROM....." to just get the count. Change it to "SElECT count(*) AS imgCount". If the imgCount is greater than 0 then you have image(s) in either primary or secondary table that match both maxWidth and maxHeight, otherwise is imgCount is 0 then the maxWidth and maxHeight belong to different image, i.e image A might have the maxWidth and image B might have the maxHeight

Comment: One caviet: I only want to be querying a certain set of images, not the whole database. Essentially, the images in `primary_images` with `imgId=$imgId`, and the images in `secondary_images with `primaryId=$imgId`. That shouldn't be too hard to add right?

Comment: Yeah, if you wouldn't mind amending your answer again, it would be greatly appreciated. I've come up with an idea, but it's not working, and I almost wish I could just post what I have. Do you think I should just start a new question, or post what I have right now as an add on to my question?

Comment: I wrote a query myself (quite proud) that works. It shows me how many entries contain both of the max values. Optimally, I would like it to show me a boolean (as we have discussed). I have added it to my question above. Would it be easy enough to change it to a boolean, or do you even think it is necessary?

Comment: @stefmikhail :) That's great! Yes, your query works and essentially behave the same with the one I put. Look at the answer that I put related to COUNT(*) comment above. The only thing is that your query does 3 aggregation functions: 2 COUNT function and 1 SUM function while mine does just 1 (COUNT). This is not a big deal for your size of records. And I think for boolean you could just detect it in the code for non-zero value (for either your or my query). You could change it in the query, but I don't think it is truly necessary.

Comment: If your `COUNT(*)` query is more efficient, then I would prefer to use it. I want to get in the habit of using best practices as often as possible. I tested your last example again, and it works fine and all, except it's searching *all* the rows in both tables, instead of only the ones in `primary_images` with `imgId = $imgId`, and the ones in `secondary_images` with `primaryId = $imgId`. How would I amend yours to refine the query as I've stated?

Comment: I've also realized I need to know how many images in that set have *only* the `maxWidth`, and also how many have only the `maxHeight`. I realize I could just repeat the query twice more with only those conditions, but I'm thinking it might not be too difficult to put them all together in `one` query. I have a feeling your `COUNT` query would be better than my `SUM` query for this, so before I post another question to combine those three, I want to know from you which would be better for combining?

Comment: Right, I figured it out (using your `COUNT`). I added `primaryId = $imgId` in the WHERE clause, but it only returned one result. Then I remembered that since you put `imgId AS primaryId` in the `primary_images` part of the query, there were duplicate columns (I think I'm saying that right), so I had to change it from `UNION` to `UNION ALL`. Now it's working like a charm. See, I'm learning! Hope you don't mind me editing your answer to show this.

Comment: @stefmikhail That is an awesome work. We all are learning here  :)

Comment: Thanks pal. I posted a new question to combine my three queries. Would love if you took a look at it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449880/combine-three-sql-queries

Answer (score 3):

[Original answer is below - this should be better]

I think I misunderstood your question. The following query should give a result set that includes one row for each image that has greatest height or greatest width compared to all images, and it will have the ID and table name in the row along with the height and width.

Since the maximum height and width may not be from the same image, there can't necessarily be just one row in the result with a single image ID and table source.

I hope this is at least closer to what you were looking for.

```
SELECT
  imgId,
  tName,
  imgWidth,
  imgHeight
FROM (
        SELECT imgId, 'Primary' tName, imgHeight, imgWidth
        FROM primary_images WHERE imgId=$imgId
        UNION 
        SELECT imgId, 'Secondary' tName, imgHeight, imgWidth
        FROM secondary_images WHERE primaryId=$imgId
      ) as T
WHERE 
 (T.imgHeight >= (SELECT MAX(imgHeight) FROM primary_images)
  AND
  T.imgHeight >= (SELECT MAX(imgHeight) FROM secondary_images)
 )
 OR
 (T.imgWidth >= (SELECT MAX(imgWidth) FROM primary_images)
  AND
  T.imgWidth >= (SELECT MAX(imgWidth) FROM secondary_images)
 )
```

-- ORIGINAL ANSWER BELOW --

Try something like this:

```
   SELECT
      imgId,
      tName,
      MAX(imgWidth) maxWidth,
      MAX(imgHeight) maxHeight FROM (
        SELECT imgId, 'Primary' tName, imgHeight, imgWidth
        FROM primary_images WHERE imgId=$imgId
        UNION 
        SELECT imgId, 'Secondary' tName, imgHeight, imgWidth
        FROM secondary_images WHERE primaryId=$imgId
      ) as T
   GROUP BY imgId, tName;
```

(MaxHeight wasn't a good alias name for the derived table, because it isn't a table of maximum heights. I changed it to T.)

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I will test it out and let you know!

Comment: @Steve Kass - Sorry to ask this; I'm still learning. I have been placing the queried values in variables using the following: `$maxImageWidth = $dimension_array[maxWidth];` and `$maxImageHeight = $dimension_array[maxHeight];`. How should I place `imgId` and `tName` in variables? The same way?

Comment: @Steve Kass - I'm pretty sure you accidentally left the `) as MaxHeight` in the code. I will edit.

Comment: @Steve Kass - So, I got the query working. But I'm not sure what the `imgId` and `tName` are referring to? I printed the array and there is one value for each selected column. The problem is, I am trying to find the `imgId` and table name for *each* the `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` values. The goal is to compare them and see if they come from the same image, or different images. Is this query able to do this?

Comment: @Steve Kass - Thanks for the updated answer. Curious, how should I extract the information using PHP? I'm using `mysql_fetch_assoc` and then printing the array result, but when I do that this is the information I get: `Array
(
    [imgId] => 16
    [tName] => Primary
    [imgWidth] => 593
    [imgHeight] => 900
)'` and I don't think that's what you were intending, was it? I don't know what that relates to?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've got so far. It looks (and probably is) heavily suboptimal. Nevertheless, I'm posting it primarily to present the general idea. Hopefully, someone might develop it so as to make the result more efficient:

```
SELECT
  m.maxWidth,
  m.maxHeight,
  (u.imgWidth IS NOT NULL) AS OneImageHasBoth
FROM (
  SELECT
    MAX(imgWidth)  AS maxWidth,
    MAX(imgHeight) AS maxHeight
  FROM (
    SELECT imgWidth, imgHeight
    FROM primary_images
    UNION
    SELECT imgWidth, imgHeight
    FROM secondary_images
  ) u
) m
  LEFT JOIN  (
    SELECT imgWidth, imgHeight
    FROM primary_images
    UNION
    SELECT imgWidth, imgHeight
    FROM secondary_images
  ) u ON m.maxWidth = u.imgWidth AND m.maxHeight = u.imgHeight
```

Obviously, one way to optimise this could be to store the result of the repeating union into a temporary table. I'm not sure if your particular environment allows you to issue multi-statement queries, but if it does, that would definitely help to speed up the query.

Your idea of finding the results for each table separately and then combining them is actually not bad. But I think the logic behind combining the results should be a bit more complex. One obvious example would be, the result for one table contains `true` and the other `false` but the latter has bigger width and height, so returning `true` would be incorrect. Or consider this example:

Suppose, the result for `primary_images` is

```
maxWidth  maxHeight  OneImageHasBoth
--------  ---------  ---------------
1152      864        true
```

and for `secondary_images` it's

```
maxWidth  maxHeight  OneImageHasBoth
--------  ---------  ---------------
1280      800        true
```

Both tables have images with both attributes maximal, but it is clear that if the query was applied to the unioned set, `OneImageHasBoth` would be `false`.

So, as you can see, combining the two results should be more intricate than merely relying on the presence of `true` in one of them.

Here's my attempt at implementing the method:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN p.maxWidth  > s.maxWidth  THEN p.maxWidth  ELSE s.maxWidth  END AS maxWidth,
  CASE WHEN p.maxHeight > s.maxHeight THEN p.maxHeight ELSE s.maxHeight END AS maxHeight,
  (
    p.maxWidth >= s.maxWidth AND p.maxHeight >= s.maxHeight AND p.OneImageHasBoth OR
    p.maxWidth <= s.maxWidth AND p.maxHeight <= s.maxHeight AND s.OneImageHasBoth
  ) AS OneImageHasBoth
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    m.maxWidth,  m.maxHeight,
    (i.imgWidth IS NOT NULL) AS OneImageHasBoth
  FROM (
    SELECT
      MAX(imgWidth)  AS maxWidth,
      MAX(imgHeight) AS maxHeight
    FROM primary_images
  ) m
    LEFT JOIN primary_images i ON m.maxWidth = i.imgWidth AND m.maxHeight = i.imgHeight
) p
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    m.maxWidth,  m.maxHeight,
    (i.imgWidth IS NOT NULL) AS OneImageHasBoth
  FROM (
    SELECT
      MAX(imgWidth)  AS maxWidth,
      MAX(imgHeight) AS maxHeight
    FROM secondary_images
  ) m
    LEFT JOIN secondary_images i ON m.maxWidth = i.imgWidth AND m.maxHeight = i.imgHeight
) s
```

Comment: So I tested out the code. Your first idea alas did not provide the proper data. I tested it on a set of images that are all the same width and height, and the query returned the same max dimensions for width & height (I know they are not, although the value was correct for maxheight), as well it returned a `0` for `OneImageHasBoth` which I'm assuming means false, which should have returned true. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your second query is using things I haven't come across yet, not saying that I don't want to learn, but that I can't begin to understand how you're doing what you're doing. Also, it returned the following error when I tried to print the answers as an array: `MySql ErrorUnknown column 'u.imgWidth' in 'field list'`. Any idea what that means?

Comment: Just an idea: My original plan was to find all the `imgId` and `table name` for both the `maxWidth` value and `maxHeight` value (if there would be more than one for each, then return multiple pairings of `imgId` & `table name`), and then using PHP, compare the two arrays to see if any of the pairings matched, thus returning true. I'm wondering if perhaps this would not be easier than what you're doing above. Not that I'm not thanking you for it, I just don't really understand it, and unless you don't mind explaining it to me, It's going to be hard for me to get it to work. And ideas?

Comment: @stefmikhail: I'll look into both queries to investigate. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @stefmikhail: Could it be that you took the first query's code before I applied a fix to it (`u.imgWidth IS NULL` to `u.imgWidth IS NOT NULL`)? That was some time before I posted the other query. Speaking of which, I fixed the wrong aliases, but other than that I agree that it looks clumsy. The idea of finding images with either of the maximums and then matching the two lists had occurred to me earlier, before posting this answer, in fact. It could be nicely implemented if MySQL supported FULL JOIN. There are workarounds for FULL JOIN, but the result might turn out as crazy as my second query.

Comment: I don't know if you have been following my discussion with momo, but we have realized that all I am really looking for is the `count` of entries. Thus I don't really need to know which images have both of the max values for their width and height, only if at least one image exists with both. I'm not sure if this was already what you were doing, but momo has been working with using the found max values from the original query in my question, to set up a second `count` query. Any ideas? I'll test out your code again to see if that was it.

Comment: Yes, both queries only return the fact whether there's an image with both max values. I would like you to focus on the first query. It's pretty straightforward: the two tables are combined, then the maximums are obtained, then they (the maximums) are matched against the same combined list of attribute pairs to see whether there's a match. If your results were just opposite to what they should have been, I've no doubt it was because of the wrong condition that I fixed later.

Comment: OK, I implemented it, and these are the results: `Array
(
    [maxWidth] => 900
    [maxHeight] => 900
    [OneImageHasBoth] => 1
)`. I'm assuming `1` for `OneImageHasBoth` means true, and `0` would be false? As for the max dimensions... they are not correct. The `maxHeight` is indeed `900`, but the `maxWidth` should be `593`. Any idea why that's not working? I'm also going to amend my question with the current separate query I have got working, just so you can take a look.

Comment: It seems like there's a mix-up of names somewhere in the code. Mine is tested thoroughly enough, although I have now looked through it again to make sure. Apart from that, is `[OneImageHasBoth] => 1` correct according to your data?

Comment: Hmm, I'll take a look at the names tonight when I get home. But yes, apart from what I mentioned, `[OneImageHasBoth] => 1` is indeed correct. Although I've now realized that the way I wrote the second query up top, where it finds the number of images that have both the max values, is exactly what I need for something else on my page. And I've also realized that having them as separate queries also suits my needs. So thank you a bunch for all your help, and I will let you know if I can figure out what was wrong with the answer, but if you have better things to do, go ahead! Cheers!

Comment: @stefmikhail: Thank you too for the interesting question!