# Combine Three SQL Queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following three SQL queries. I would like to combine them into one is possible, either using the current method, or another method if it would be more efficient.

NOTE: I need to know the distinct count values for all three WHERE clauses.

**Query 1:**

```
SElECT COUNT(*) AS imgCount FROM (
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, imgId AS primaryId FROM primary_images
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, primaryId FROM secondary_images
) AS union_table
WHERE primaryId = $imgId AND imgWidth = $maxImageWidth AND imgHeight = $maxImageHeight;
```

**QUERY 2:**

```
SElECT COUNT(*) AS imgCount FROM (
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, imgId AS primaryId FROM primary_images
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, primaryId FROM secondary_images
) AS union_table
WHERE primaryId = $imgId AND imgWidth = $maxImageWidth AND imgHeight != $maxImageHeight;
```

**QUERY 3:**

```
SElECT COUNT(*) AS imgCount FROM (
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, imgId AS primaryId FROM primary_images
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, primaryId FROM secondary_images
) AS union_table
WHERE primaryId = $imgId AND imgWidth != $maxImageWidth AND imgHeight = $maxImageHeight;
```

---

Also, my database is MySQL. I have heard that using `!=` for "not equal" doesn't work in all cases, but that `<>` is better. In my case, should `!=` be fine?

Comment: `!=` and `<>` are equivalents in MySQL, there is no difference between them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might work for you.

```
SElECT COUNT(*) AS imgCount FROM (
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, imgId AS primaryId FROM primary_images
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, primaryId FROM secondary_images
) AS union_table
WHERE primaryId = $imgId 
AND (imgWidth != $maxImageWidth AND imgHeight = $maxImageHeight
OR imgWidth = $maxImageWidth AND imgHeight != $maxImageHeight
OR imgWidth = $maxImageWidth AND imgHeight = $maxImageHeight);
```

I also believe this is equivalent, although I'm not sure.

```
SElECT COUNT(*) AS imgCount FROM (
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, imgId AS primaryId FROM primary_images
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, primaryId FROM secondary_images
) AS union_table
WHERE primaryId = $imgId 
AND (imgWidth = $maxImageWidth OR imgHeight = $maxImageHeight);
```

As per the request, here is a single query that returns 3 rows.

```
SELECT 'ALL EQUAL' AS COL1,COUNT(*) AS imgCount FROM (
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, imgId AS primaryId FROM primary_images
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, primaryId FROM secondary_images
) AS union_table
WHERE primaryId = $imgId AND imgWidth = $maxImageWidth AND imgHeight = $maxImageHeight
UNION ALL
SELECT 'WIDTH EQUAL' AS COL1,COUNT(*) AS imgCount FROM (
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, imgId AS primaryId FROM primary_images
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, primaryId FROM secondary_images
) AS union_table
WHERE primaryId = $imgId AND imgWidth = $maxImageWidth AND imgHeight != $maxImageHeight;
UNION ALL
SELECT 'HEIGHT EQUAL' AS COL1,COUNT(*) AS imgCount FROM (
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, imgId AS primaryId FROM primary_images  
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, primaryId FROM secondary_images
) AS union_table
WHERE primaryId = $imgId AND imgWidth != $maxImageWidth AND imgHeight = $maxImageHeight;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Curious, will that provide me with three different values? I guess I should have mentioned that in the question. I need to know the distinct count values for all three WHERE clauses. Also, I'm a little unsure as to why, inside the WHERE clause, the following line `AND ($imgId AND` has `$imgId` inside it?

Comment: No, that will only provide you with 1 value, if you want 3 different values, wait a minute while I compose an answer for that.  Also, as you may nave noticed, I edited the "$imgid AND" part out

Comment: no prob.  It was a little ambiguous as to what "combine" meant in this case.  Hope my latest addition solves your problems

Comment: Alas I'm getting a syntax error for the following: `AND imgHeight = UNION ALL SELECT 'WIDTH EQUAL' AS COL1,COUNT(*) AS imgCount FRO`. Any ideas?

Comment: @stefmikhail This means that `$maxImageHeight` is NULL or empty string.

Comment: @Karolis - Right. I figured that out. Fixed that, but now I'm getting the syntax error: `UNION ALL SELECT 'HEIGHT EQUAL' AS COL1,COUNT(*) AS imgCount FROM ( SELECT i`. Now what?

Comment: @stefmikhail I think it's because of semicolon before UNION ALL. Just remove it.

Comment: @Karolis - Indeed that was what it was. I should have caught that. This is what I am returned: `Array
(
    [COL1] => ALL EQUAL
    [imgCount] => 2
)`. I was expecting three values. What does this translate as?

Comment: @stefmikhail You should loop throw the result set. Actually there are three arrays :)

Comment: @Karolis - Well then! Care to give me a hint as to how I should go about looping as you've stated, using PHP?

Comment: @stefmikhail It depends on MySQL library you use. For instance look at example #1 in this page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: @Karolis - I'm already using `mysql_fetch_assoc` to find my result. I will investigate to see if I'm using it incorrectly. Thanks.

Comment: @stefmikhail Yes, but you shoud use a **loop** together with `mysql_fetch_assoc` :)

Comment: @Karolis - I used `while` to loop through the data as your recommended, and it produced three sets of results as expected. Thank you for the help. I just have to figure out how to placed the data from the loop inside PHP variables. Will the results always be in the same order? I would love some advice... even if it's a link. Here are the results by the way: `Array
(
    [COL1] => ALL EQUAL
    [imgCount] => 2
)
Array
(
    [COL1] => WIDTH EQUAL
    [imgCount] => 0
)
Array
(
    [COL1] => HEIGHT EQUAL
    [imgCount] => 0
)`

Comment: @stefmikhail In theory there is no guarantee that order will always be the same. But you can add `order by col1` at the end of your sql query, then the order will be preserved.

Comment: @Karolis - And how do I place the retrieved values into PHP variables? I've only ever used `while` to echo results. I'm starting to think perhaps I might have to leave them as three separate queries :(

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($row['COL1'] == 'ALL EQUAL') $all_equal = $row['imgCount'];
}

Comment: @stefmikhail `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { $cnt[$row['COL1']] = $row['imgCount']; }`. And now you will have one array with three values: `$cnt['ALL EQUAL']`, `$cnt['WIDTH EQUAL']` and `$cnt['HEIGHT EQUAL']`.

Comment: @Karolis - Excellent! Thanks for that. For some reason however, only the `WIDTH EQUAL` and `HEIGHT EQUAL` are being returned. This was happening before your last comment. It's strange because the first time I tested this with the loop, it returned all three of the desired values; Now it's only returning the last two. Any ideas? I just don't know what would have changed to have caused this? I appreciate all your help, and I understand if you're done with this question.

Comment: @stefmikhail Really don't know. Check your query and/or other PHP code. Perhaps you did some changes and now you have a typo or something :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that a CASE and a GROUP BY are needed:

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN imgWidth  = $maxImageWidth AND imgHeight  = $maxImageHeight
       THEN 0
       WHEN imgWidth != $maxImageWidth AND imgHeight  = $maxImageHeight
       THEN 1
       WHEN imgWidth  = $maxImageWidth AND imgHeight != $maxImageHeight
       THEN 2
       END AS count_type,
       COUNT(*) AS imgCount
  FROM (SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, imgId AS primaryId FROM primary_images
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, primaryId FROM secondary_images
       ) AS union_table
 WHERE primaryId = $imgId
   AND (imgWidth = $maxImageWidth OR imgHeight = $maxImageHeight)
 GROUP BY count_type;
```

It is at least tempting to push the WHERE clause down into the UNION subqueries, but the optimizer should do that anyway.  Do check that it does do that by studying the EXPLAIN output.  If the optimizer does not do the predicate pushdown automatically, you'd write:

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN imgWidth  = $maxImageWidth AND imgHeight  = $maxImageHeight
       THEN 0
       WHEN imgWidth != $maxImageWidth AND imgHeight  = $maxImageHeight
       THEN 1
       WHEN imgWidth  = $maxImageWidth AND imgHeight != $maxImageHeight
       THEN 2
       END AS count_type,
       COUNT(*) AS imgCount
  FROM (SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, imgId AS primaryId FROM primary_images
         WHERE primaryId = $imgId  -- or: imgId = $imgId
           AND (imgWidth = $maxImageWidth OR imgHeight = $maxImageHeight)
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, primaryId FROM secondary_images
         WHERE primaryId = $imgId
           AND (imgWidth = $maxImageWidth OR imgHeight = $maxImageHeight)
       ) AS union_table
 GROUP BY count_type;
```

The disadvantage of this solution as written is that the `$maxImageWidth` and `$maxImageHeight` variables are used 4 times each (and `$imgId` once).  If you are preparing the statement as shown (embedding the values in the string representing the SQL), it isn't too bad. If you are using placeholders, you need a naming scheme for the placeholders if possible (`:img_ht`, `:img_wd`, `:img_id` (or at least `:1`, `:2`, `:3`) in place of the `?` placeholders) so you only pass each value once in the EXECUTE statement.  That capability depends on your DBMS, though; MySQL is one of a number of DBMS that do not support this facility.

Comment: I'll test that out. Just wondering, would the UNION ALL not automatically GROUP? Or am I thinking of something else? I'm still learning.

Comment: UNION ALL has nothing to do with grouping; it simply means that all repeats are preserved.  To get grouping, you have to do GROUP BY somewhere.

Comment: Yes, figured that out, and thank you. I'm getting the following returned to me: `Array
(
    [count_type] => 0
    [imgCount] => 2
)`. I was expecting three values. How should I interpret this data?

Comment: The result you show would indicate that for your test ID, there were two exactly sized images, no images with the right height but wrong width, and no images with the right width but wrong height.  If you want explicit zeroes for the two 'missing' cases, then you have to do some extra work.  Or, possibly, it indicates that you fetched just one row when you needed to fetch three rows.  However, given the appearance of '`Array`' in your data, I think it is a question of what data is present in the tables.  I trust both image tables have an index on the relevant ID columns.

Comment: @Jonathan This array is not multidimensional, so I think this means that it's an array of one fetched row.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - The last two comments lead me to understand there is some conjecture as to the validity of your explanation of the results I provided. If your explanation is correct, then there is a problem as I need to place the returned values from each WHERE clause in a variable to use. If your explanation is incorrect, does that mean I have to use a loop to find the results?

Comment: @stefmikhail: how you retrieve the results is not so much pure SQL and more the programming language. You should be retrieving up to 3 rows from the query, each containing two values. One value, named `count_type`, indicates the degree of match (0 match on height and width, 1 match on height, 2 match on width); the other, named `imgCount`, is the corresponding number of images. Therefore, you need a loop to fetch all the rows. Your tripartite query returned 3 rows in three operations (with no loop); this returns up to 3 rows but requires a loop of some form, possibly a 'fetch all' function.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have indexes on primaryId in your primary_images and secondary_images tables? If yes, then you should push the where clause inside so that the indexes can be used.

```
SElECT COUNT(*) AS imgCount FROM (
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, imgId AS primaryId FROM primary_images WHERE imgId = $imgId AND imgWidth != $maxImageWidth AND imgHeight = $maxImageHeight 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, primaryId FROM secondary_images WHERE primaryId = $imgId AND imgWidth != $maxImageWidth AND imgHeight = $maxImageHeight
) AS union_table
```

Otherwise it will be a full table scan to find the imgId as union_table is a temporary table created by Mysql and doesn't have any indexes.

Comment: I do indeed have `primaryId` indexed in the secondary_images table, but it does not exist in the primary_images table. The index is on `imgId` on the primary_images table. That's why I had `imgId AS primaryId`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: You need to rewrite your query in the manner I suggested in order for Mysql to use the indexes you created on the two tables. 

The table union_table is a temporary table created by Mysql and it doesn't have any indexes. However, if you push the where clause to apply on primary_images and secondary_images tables, Mysql can use the respective indexes on those tables and that's a good thing!

Comment: That is *indeed* a good thing. I tested your suggestion and I received the following array: `Array
(
    [imgCount] => 0
)`. I know that there are 2 images that have *both* the values, and 0 that have just one. Do I have to use a loop? Is that why I'm only getting one result?

Comment: Well, the query above is just a rewritten version of your Query 3. Its result should be the same as the result for your Query 3.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well thanks for that. I'm trying to put them all together, but it doesn't seem to be working out for me very well as I need to results in variables, and I can't figure out how to do that. So I might just have to use independent queries instead, in which case I will use your advice! Thanks!